# How to tell a curl max-time apart from a connect-timeout?

Tags: bash, unix, curl

Example command

```
curl -s -w "%{http_code} %{http_connect}" --connect-timeout 10 --max-time 50
```

Will return `000 000` for both the connect-timeout being reached and the max-time being reached. What is the best way to tell these two errors apart?

The only difference, as far as I can see, is when the `-s` flag is removed:

- Connection timeout returns `curl: (28) connect() timed out` and
- Max timeout returns `curl: (28) Operation timed out`

Comment: Do `%{time_total}` and/or `%{time_connect}` help at all here?

Comment: On a connection where there is no response for n seconds (triggering `--connect-timeout`) I noticed there is a lack of HTTP status code in the verbose output of `curl`. Conversely an established connection passing the `--max-time` threshold will have this information in. Could you perform some checks on the verbose output?

Comment: @Lewis Norton: If `--connect-timeout` is tripped there is no HTTP status since there was no connection to begin with.  However, if `--max-time` it doesn't necessarily follow that you'll have a status, since the connection can be cut off after it was established, but before a first HTTP response has been received.

Comment: @lcd047 Quite true actually. I did not think of that.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a better way to distinguish these two failures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two points in your question:

- HTTP CODE
- Distinguish the difference

#### HTTP CODE

When the order is failed, there will be no http code.Because there is no reponse.You can acquire the http code only when the order is success.

#### Distinguish the difference

You can gain the error by the follow order.

```
result=`curl  --connect-timeout $connectiontimeout --max-time $maxtimeout -s -S -X POST -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' -d "$DATA" "$resturl" 1>&1 2>&1`

if [ "$result" = "curl: (28) connect() timed out" ] ;then
    echo "curl: (28) connect() timed out"

fi
```

Then you can judge the result to distinguish the two error.

Comment: It is better to compare curl’s exit code (28, in this case) instead of trying to compare curl’s output as a string. That’s because the details of the output might change, causing the comparison to fail. On the other hand, the meaning of the exit codes never changes, as explained in the curl(1) manual page.